# Modifying Permissions of Control Panel on Liferay

Tags: liferay

I want to give permissions to certain user groups on Liferay 6.0.5 so that they can access certain parts of the control panel, such as allowing them to change their email. How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the own email address is typically enabled by default. See this entry in portal.properties (or override in your portal-ext.properties)

```
#
# Input a list of comma delimited user types who can edit their own fields.
# Valid types are "administrator", "user-with-mx", and "user-without-mx".
#
# Set a value of "administrator" if an administrator can edit the specified
# field. An administrator is anyone who has the Administrator role.
#
# Set a value of "user-with-mx" if a user who has an email address that
# matches the company mail suffix can edit the specified field.
#
# Set a value of "user-without-mx" if a user who does not have an email
# address that matches the company mail suffix can edit the specified field.
#
# Set all three values if all users can edit the specified field. Set a
# combination of the three values if only a combination of the users can
# edit the specified field.
#
field.editable.com.liferay.portal.model.User.screenName=administrator,user-with-mx,user-without-mx
field.editable.com.liferay.portal.model.User.emailAddress=administrator,user-with-mx,user-without-mx
```

For other control panel content: Create a  custom role, choose "Define Permissions" and in the select box in the section "ControlPanel" you'll find a permission named "Access in ControlPanel". Of course, you'll need the additional permissions for the parts that you allow access to as well (see e.g. under the Content section in the select box)

Comment: For some reason, I had trouble with this so I just went to edit the jsp itself. Thanks though.